# Separating date and time from the same column into two columns

Tags: arcmap, datetime

If I have date and time in the same column how can I separate them in two columns in ArcMap?
And how can I put the date in this format (year,month,day)?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

Use `DatePart("PART", [DATEFIELD])` in the Field Calculator.

> The PART argument can be one of the following keywords: yyyy (YEAR), m
> (MONTH), d (DAY), h (HOUR), n (MINUTE), or s (SECOND)

See here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014933